# cuda device function that return array

Tags: cuda

Try to find solution for this:
Cuda Kernel uses several **device** functions, some of them need to return array.

I try to do this:

```
__device__ float *MatProd2dWxC(float *a2d, float  *b2d, int mGl, int nGl)
{
    int aRows = mGl; int aCols = nGl;
    int bRows = nGl; int bCols = 1;

    float *result;
    //result.resize(mGl*aRows);

    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; ++i) // each row of a
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of b
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) 
                result[i*mGl + j] += a2d[i*mGl + k] * b2d[k*mGl + j];

    return result;
}
```

Don't compile this because understand that pointer in function name is not good idea. But how to do right, as idea to include additional temp array and change function to void. but then I need to use it many times in kernel code, look for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a pointer from a device function is ok and works just fine.

The problem in your code is that you do not assign any value to the `result` pointer which you then dereference and also return from the function later. You need to use `float *result = malloc(mGl*aRows * sizeof(float));` to allocate memory (and don't forget to `free()` later!).

However a better design would be to pass an already allocated pointer *into* your device function. This establishes clear ownership of the allocation (i.e. makes it clear in your code where `free()` should be called), and may avoid unnecessary allocation in some cases, where e.g. the allocation could be pulled outside of a loop.

This problem has nothing to do with CUDA, it applies as well to standard C.

Comment: Thank for answer. this function would be used in every thread so `result` need for every thread independent, so is it possible to allocate it not from `__host__` but from  `__device__` side to exclude collisions?

Comment: To be more detailed in `Kernel` need to calculate the next formula `ft2d = MatSig2d(MatSum2d(MatProd2dWx(Wf2d, xt2d,m,n), MatProd2dUh(Uf2d, h_prev2d.m,n), bf2d));` , so idea to put `result` directly in formula

Comment: I think, you are right, make 3d array: 2d +1 additional dimension for threads

Comment: If you pass the pointer into the function (rather than malloc()ing it inside and returning it), then you can use an automatic array, which gets allocated on the stack. This is much more efficient than using an extra dimension for the thread it, because the stack allocation will only be used for all *concurrently running* threads, while your 3d array will allocate memory for *all* threads. Of course, allocating on the stack limits you to fairly small arrays as well. You might need to increase the stack size in that case.

Comment: I need array near 2500 elements, this 50x50 2d array, is this suitable for stack?  and how to pass pointer into the function in some more words,  if I need to send size of array through kernel to function.